# Create WebService Client from URI in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, web-services, import, wsdl

i want to make some tests with the Oracle Business Intelligence Webservices. First i want to import them into Eclipse. For that i use this howto:

http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html

Until step 8 is everything okay. For the Import i'm using:

http://localhost:9704/analytics/saw.dll?WSDL

But then i get following error:

```
IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.
  invalid segment: web/soap/v4.analytics.siebel.com
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid segment: web/soap/v4.analytics.siebel.com
      at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.validateURI(URI.java:1070)
      at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createHierarchicalURI(URI.java:482)
      at org.eclipse.jem.java.internal.impl.JavaRefFactoryImpl.createTypeURI(JavaRefFactoryImpl.java:509)
      at org.eclipse.jem.java.internal.impl.JavaRefFactoryImpl.reflectType(JavaRefFactoryImpl.java:472)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.common.JavaMOFUtils.getJavaClass(JavaMOFUtils.java:212)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.Stub2BeanInfo.writeSEIMethods(Stub2BeanInfo.java:475)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.Stub2BeanInfo.writeClass(Stub2BeanInfo.java:239)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.Stub2BeanInfo.write(Stub2BeanInfo.java:168)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.Stub2BeanCommand.execute(Stub2BeanCommand.java:197)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.ClientCodeGenOperation$ClientWSModifyOperation.execute(ClientCodeGenOperation.java:110)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.ui.task.ClientCodeGenOperation.execute(ClientCodeGenOperation.java:61)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
      at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:446)
      at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:354)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:934)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:380)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:742)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
      at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3823)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3422)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:253)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:273)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:281)
      at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
      at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:247)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:583)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:500)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3823)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3422)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2382)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2346)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2198)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:493)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:488)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
```

I have already searched for a solution. It looks like a bug, so that I need a webserver. But i have a Tomcat, which is already running (see screenshot here: http://i41.tinypic.com/ere5vp.jpg)

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve the problem?

Regards,
Sirakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another howtos and now is everything okay :)

http://gerardnico.com/wiki/ide/eclipse/eclipse_how_to_consume_a_webservice_with_wtp
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/web_server/oc4j/oc4j_eclipse_configuration